# Socket Python read bynary data

Tags: python, sockets

I am getting information from a socket via UDP.
I do not know how to read, this type of date below is binary, hexadecimal ???

```
��=~%01.00 EB200318151C0000003s��Z�t|
```

This is the result of part:

```
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) 
    print "received message:", data
```

Can someone help, what kind of information is coming, how should I read it?

Comment: You need to look at the protocol documentation for whatever it is that's transmitting that to you.

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We have no idea what you are getting it from.

Comment: What kind of information is coming, it's binary type data?

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    data, addr = s.recv(1024)
    print "received message:" + data
```